# Unable to load images for GridView from drawable using Universal Image Loader

Tags: android, gridview, universal-image-loader

I'm calling the UIL's `displayImage` method but it is not accepting the image URI. Here is my code for `getView`. I'm getting the error:

`UnsupportedOperationException: UIL doesn't support scheme(protocol) by default [2130837504]. You should implement this support yourself (BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromOtherSource(...))`

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_view_card_layout, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.participantName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_model_name);
            holder.participantCountry = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_country_name);
            holder.participantImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_model_image);
            holder.progressBar = (ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.progress);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        applyTypeFace(convertView);

        holder.participantName.setText(ParticipantName[position]);
        holder.participantCountry.setText(ParticipantCountry[position]);
        //holder.participantImage.setImageResource(ImageId[position]);

        //Here lies the problem
        ImageLoader.getInstance()
                .displayImage(String.valueOf(ImageId[position]), holder.participantImage);

        return convertView;
    }
```

Any help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use "drawable://" + id of the drawable resource

Example:

```
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage("drawable://" + R.drawable.icon_teste,holder.participantImage);
```

If you're trying to get the drawable by it's name instead of the id you can get it's identifier using this:

```
int id = getContext().getResources().getIdentifier(ICON_NAME, "drawable", getContext().getPackageName());
```

Comment: `String.valueOf("drawable://" + ImageId[position])` worked! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Check your image string it should be from [readme](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader#acceptable-uris-examples)

```
String imageUri = "assets://image.png"; // from assets
String imageUri = "drawable://" + R.drawable.image; // from drawables (only images, non-9patch)
```